# Sii - Libro Facturas Recibidas - mas de una

Tags: aeat-sii

Estamos intentando armar el XML para el LRFR.
hemos tenido exito con una linea de factura, pero no logramos descifrar cómo armar un XML con mas de una linea de factura.
Vemos varios ejemplos para el LRFE, pero no para el LRFR.... ¿alguien tiene un ejemplo para ésta casuistica?

Comment: Buenas, por favor, revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Parece una duda bastante simple de resolver...

Hay dos grandes bloques en el XML LRFR, la Cabecera y el RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas.
El segundo bloque es el que se puede repetir. Algo así:

```
<siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas>
    <sii:Cabecera>
        ... info cabecera ...
    </sii:Cabecera>
    <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas>
        ... info factura 1 ...
    </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas>
    <siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas>
        ... info factura 2 ...
    </siiLR:RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas>
</siiLR:SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas>
```